# Jquery expand collapse next row of the table on click of span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a table which is having **+** and **-** items for expand and collapse. Onclick of this icons row next to that particular row should expand . I am adding collpasible Icon dynamically through jquery. How can I access next rows dynamically on click of these icons.

[image]

Ideally on click of that **-** icon that expanded row should hide and onclick of **+** it should be shown.. Thanks in advance

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".table tbody tr.has-history td:first-child").append('<span class="collapse-icon"></span>');
});
```

```css
.table tbody tr.has-history > td:first-child {
  position: relative;
}
.table tbody tr.has-history span.collapse-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  background: #f09d18;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.table tbody tr.has-history span.collapse-icon:before {
  content: "+";
}
.table tbody tr.has-history.open span.collapse-icon {
  background: #eee;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.table tbody tr.has-history.open span.collapse-icon:before {
  content: "-";
}
.table{
MARGIN-LEFT:40px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Config</th>
            <th>Version</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="has-history open">
            <td><a href="#">MSM8992</a></td>
            <td>Estel</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="expanded">
            <td colspan="4">
                <table class="table" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Product</th>
                          <th>Config</th>
                          <th>Version</th>
                          <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr>
                           <td><a href="#">MSM8994</a></td>
                          <td>Elessar</td>
                          <td>1</td>
                          <td>Active</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">MSM8994</a></td>
            <td>Elessar</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">APQ8084</a></td>
            <td>Gandalf - PoP Memory</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="has-history">
            <td><a href="#">MDM9x40</a></td>
            <td>Tesla</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">MDM9x45</a></td>
            <td>Spark</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="has-history">
            <td><a href="#">APQ8084</a></td>
            <td>Gandalf - External Memory</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind click event on collapse-icon class

Toggle next row and icon on click

```
$(document).on("click", ".collapse-icon", function() {
$(this).parents(".has-history").next().slideToggle();
$(this).parents(".has-history").toggleClass("open");
});
```

Refer this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k6kn972b/

Answer (score 1):

Bind click event using event delegation

Then target the current row using `$(this).closest("tr")`

Then get the next row using `.next()`

```
 $(document).on("click", ".collapse-icon", function() {
   $(this).closest("tr").next().slideToggle();
 });
```